# Complex filtering of dataframe based on time difference between two events using R

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

This is a sample dataset of three variables, one for the student id, second for the test date and third for the test subject.
using r filtering (base or dplyr) , I was trying to identify the students who had less than 30 days between any english and any math test? ie does not matter which test occurred first.

I tried the code below (mostly with the help of LLMs) but did not work.

```
df <- data.frame(student_id = c("A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A"),
                 date = as.Date(c("2022-01-02", "2022-05-02", "2022-04-07", "2022-03-09", "2022-04-02", "2022-04-02", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-01", "2022-05-10", "2022-01-17", "2022-04-02")),
                 test = c("english", "science", "math", "english", "math", "science", "english", "math", "math", "math", "science"))
```

This is the answer I am getting from gpt:

```
# group the data by student ID
df_grouped <- df %>% group_by(student_id)

# filter the data based on the conditions
df_filtered <- df_grouped %>% 
  filter(test %in% c("english", "math")) %>% 
  mutate(diff = abs(as.numeric(difftime(date[test == "english"], date[test == "math"], units = "days")))) %>% 
  filter(diff <= 30) %>% 
  select(student_id) %>% 
  distinct()
```

gives this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `diff`.
i `diff = abs(...)`.
i `diff` must be size 3 or 1, not 2.
i The error occurred in group 1: student_id = "A".
```

Comment: One issue is that you have multiple matches; for instance, student `A` has one `"english"` and two `"math"`. Which of the two `"math"` rows should be used when calculating the diff?

Comment: Further, since you're reducing with `[test == "english"]` (etc), are you intentionally looking for a singular value to assign to all rows within that group? Would `summarize` be more appropriate for that step? (This does not fix the issue in my first comment.)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to add `min()` around the absolute to grab the shortest time, since we don't care about any other times, just the shortest:

```
# group the data by student ID
df_grouped <- df %>% group_by(student_id)

# filter the data based on the conditions
df_filtered <- df_grouped %>% 
  filter(test %in% c("english", "math")) %>% 
  mutate(diff = min(abs(as.numeric(difftime(date[test == "english"], date[test == "math"], units = "days"))))) %>% 
  filter(diff <= 30) %>% 
  select(student_id) %>% 
  distinct()
         
# Output
# A tibble: 2 × 1
# Groups:   student_id [2]
  student_id
  <chr>     
1 A         
2 C
```